# Javascript variable not working in a different file

Tags: php, javascript

I have this script in **index.php** file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ads').load('output.php').fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
```

And the **output.php** file contains a hidden input by which I pass a php variable and retrieve it succesfully:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
num = document.getElementById('number').value;
</script>
```

And if I put, say, an `alert(num);` in the **output.php** file, everything works. Though when I do the same in the **index.php** file, javascript doesn't seem to see that `num` variable.

Comment: What is the code and when/where is it in the page load that's trying to access `num`? I suspect it's trying to do so before `output.php` is loaded.

Comment: I believe jQuery strips `<script>` tags, looking at the source of `.load`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L214.

Comment: I've tried to access the NUM variable right after I've loaded the output.php file, as well as within the loading function itself;

Comment: I simply include output.php in the body, into the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access variables before you create them. In the code you provided the first time *num* is being assigned to is when the output.php file is loaded and parsed. Since jQuery's load function isn't blocking - that is, your browser will continue executing JS while the load function is doing its magic - you have no good way to know when *num* will be assigned to. It could be milliseconds, or it could be never if your webserver refuses to return the output of output.php for whatever reason.

In jQuery programming, using a callback function is common practice, although you can make it cleaner by passing it a function reference instead of an inline function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ads').load('output.php', outputLoadCallback).fadeIn('slow');
});

function outputLoadCallback(response, status) {
    console.log(num);
}
```

Maybe an even better way would be to include the logic you need to run in the callback function like so:

```
var num; // Make sure num is in the global scope
function outputLoadCallback(response, status) {
     num = document.getElementById('number').value;
     console.log(num);
}
```

If you're "not much of a pro", may I suggest [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/)?

Comment: I decided to go old clunky XMLHttpRequest way with asynchronisation set at false. Thank you for the book!)))

Comment: AJAX exists so that HTTP requests could be async. It's a good thing. It lets your site go ahead in its execution while it's fetching data. It's easy to create "loading" messages through the callbacks (in fact, that's what I specialize in when I make web apps for clients - dynamic loading). I highly suggest that you architect your application to use async AJAX calls - anything else is looking for trouble. Just my two cents :p

Answer (score 3):

Im just going to ges that you dont actually wait until the file is actually loaded before testing to access that variable

http://api.jquery.com/load/

the load method takes a completed callback that u can use like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ads').load('output.php', function() {
   alert(num);
  }).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

but you should probably not solve your problem this way i sugest you call a function from your
loaded file instead of setting a variable

Comment: It does work, though is there any way to get this variable to work outside the loading function? Sorry if this sounds silly, i'm not so much of a pro.

Comment: its global you can access it anywhere you just cant access it until it has been created